# SQL check if list parameter is null in different RDBMS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am creating an app which performs raw queries across different databases and I am struggling with list parameters (IN).

I use SQLAlchemy for performing these queries.

I want to perform a query that accepts list parameter and that parameter might be NULL, which means I don't have to filter by field.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

SQL = """SELECT group, count(1) cnt
         FROM some_table
         WHERE group IN :groups OR :groups IS NULL
         GROUP BY group
"""
params = {'groups': ('group1', 'group2')}

engine = create_engine(connection_string)
query = text(SQL).bindparams(**params)
cursor = engine.execute(query)
```

Currently I'm testing it on PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite, but in production mode it is also supposed to work with SQL Server and Oracle.

The code above works only on PostgreSQL, however if I change params with None

```
params = {'groups': None}
```

The code wouldn't work on any databases.

Is there workaround for this problem?

I understand that solution might be specific for each RDBMS.

Comment: IN is not an operator that takes a list argument, it is a syntax element, so NULL doesn't make sense here. You could use = ANY with an array in PostgreSQL but I don't know that will work for other platforms

Comment: What if you do `params = {'groups': (None)}`? Per [IN]: *The right-hand side is a parenthesized list of scalar expressions. ... Note that if the left-hand expression yields null, or if there are no equal right-hand values and at least one right-hand expression yields null, the result of the IN construct will be null, not false.*

Comment: Thanks Adrian, eventually I did this way.